# Terminal: I press "@" or "#" and terminal write "?"

Tags: terminal

I have this problem only on the terminal.

When I would like to write these symbol, for example "@" or "#" the Terminal write this "?" and a do a sound bell.

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I don't understand why.

thank you

Comment: Ok, the problem is with theme: https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/tree/master/OS%20X%20Terminal

Comment: Please post answers as answers and not by amending the question. This way it's easier for future visitors to find answers to similar problems.

Answer (score -1):

**Solved !**

Open the Terminal preferences, go to "Keyboard" tab and unpin the

```
Use option as meta key
```

:)